# wordpress is_search not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to check if Im on the search page, so I can add my own custom query parameters, but it doesnt seem to work. When I look for "this is a test", I cant find in on the search results page.

I have this code inside functions.php and im using the search.php template to display my search results.

```
if( is_search() ){
    echo 'this is a test';
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you to alter your search request.

```
function customSearch($query){
    if ( $query->is_search() ) {
         // add external search form (Google, Yahoo, Live...)
         $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }   
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','customSearch');
```

Comment: thanks @Surinder kumar, but for some reason thats not working, its strange because Ive used that same type of code on other sites and its work fine

Comment: I have tested it and its working fine for me. Can you explain a bit more where you using this code?

Comment: Im putting that code at the very end of functions.php and then im just using a standard search.php with my own small tweaks (just different code inside the query), quite strange because I know that code works as Ive used it myself on other sites.

Comment: @Adrian I’m having exactly the same situation. Is it not valid to call this function from functions.php?